$\mathcal F_{x'}(\hat{\sigma}(x', t))$ is in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ uniformly in $t\in\mathbb R$.
(major edit below)
Let $\sigma$ be the surface measure of $\mathbb S^{d-1}\subset \mathbb R^n$, $\hat{\sigma}$ be the Fourier transform of $\sigma$ and let's split the variable in $x=(x',t)$.
I'm trying to prove that $\mathcal F_{x'}(\hat{\sigma}(x', t))$, which is the transform of $\hat{\sigma}$ only in the first $d-1$ variables, still view as a function on $\mathbb R^d$, is in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ uniformly in $t\in\mathbb R$ (in the sense that this set is bounded in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$).
This fact should hold also for measures like $\mu=\psi \sigma_S$ where $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d)$ and $\sigma_S$ is the surface measure of an hypersurface $S$ with non zero curvature in supp$(\psi)$ (just to say that I don't expect a proof to rely on the symmetries of $\mathbb S^{d-1}$).
This result is stated in the proof of the Tomas-Stein theorem by fractional integration in the book by Muscalu and Schlag, but it's not motivated.
I already know that $\hat{\sigma}(x)\leq C|x|^{-\frac{d-1}{2}}$ as a consequence of the theory of oscillatory integrals (of the first kind) and I know the basics of harmonic analysis.
My "attempt" for the moment has been trying to express $\hat{\sigma}$ as an integrals on finite charts in a way that could maybe resemble an actual Fourier transform, in order to use some kind of inversion formula, but I couldn't find anything useful.
The second "idea" is to check this fact distributionally in some way, since it's not even clear that $\mathcal F_{x'}(\hat{\sigma}(x', t))$ is well defined as a funcion, but at least it's a tempered distribution for it's decay.
EDIT: For the proof of the Tomas-Stein Theorem I only need to prove this fact for the kind of surfaces I talk about in my answer (I can reduce to this case via a partition of unity, but it's not relevant for the question itself). At this point this general fact is probably false, and the partial transform may not even be well defined.
In conclusion I consider myself satisfied with the answer I gave, since it's what I needed.

I think I $\textit{almost}$ solved it and the proof shouldn't even require any condition on the curvature of $S$.
The idea is to parametrize $S$ with inverses of projections on the "canonical" hyperplanes ($\{x_m=0\}$ for an $m\in[1,d]$) and associate a partition of unity $\{\rho_j\}$ to this $\textit{finite}$ atlas (we just need to cover supp$(\psi)\cap S$), so that the Jacobian is bounded on these maps. Then if all these hyperplanes are $\{x_d=0\}$ the parametrizations have the form $\phi_j\colon U_j\subset\mathbb R^{d-1}\rightarrow S\subset \mathbb R^{d}$ with $\phi_j=(\text{Id}_{\mathbb R^{d-1}},\psi_j)$ and we have
$$\hat{\mu}(x',t)=\sum_j\int e^{-2\pi i( x'\cdot y'+t\cdot \psi_j(y'))}J_{\phi_j}(y')\rho_j(\phi_j(y'))\text dy'=\sum_j \int e^{-2\pi i (x'\cdot y') }(e^{-2\pi i t\cdot \psi_j(y')}J_{\phi_j}(y')\rho_j(\phi_j(y')))\text dy'=\sum_j\int e^{-2\pi i x'\cdot y'}h_{j,t}(y')\text dy'=\sum_j\widehat{h_{j,t}}(x').$$
Therefore $\mathcal F_{x'}(\hat{\mu})(\xi',t)=\sum_j \overline{h_{j,t}(-\xi')}$ for the inversion formula and so $\|\mathcal F_{x'}(\hat{\mu})\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)}\leq \sum_j\|h_{j,t}\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)}$ which is finite and doesn't depend on $t$, since $|e^{-2\pi i t\cdot \psi_j(y')}|=1$.
The only problem with this approach is that of course not all the hyperplanes of the parametrizations $\phi_j$ have this form, which is $\{x_d=0\}$. However I'm pretty sure that there is a way to adapt the other cases to this one, but I can't find it.
It could be that the non vanishing curvature is actually needed so that the set where you can't project on $\{x_d=0\}$ (which means that the differential of the projection map isn't an isomorphism, or equivalently that $e_n$ belongs to the tangent space) is negligible in an approriate way, but I don't know enough riemannian geometry to prove this or to use it. For example in $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ the only problem is in $\mathbb S^{d-1}\cap \{x_d=0\}$ and you could cover $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ in 3 pieces where one of these is a very thin strip around this copy of $\mathbb S^{d-2}$ (and then I don't know).
